# Android Studio App Crash When I Add Google Play Services Library (Google Admob)

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

**When I add this library:** implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0' **my app not open and crash when Delete this library and related code then working correct, why I need to fix this here error showing below. And I want to place ads please help me.**

E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.pref_scale_resolution"
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hannanmentor.sciencimalumaat, PID: 17041
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7587)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7035)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:263)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2032)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:268)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:627)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:997)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzek.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.2.0:26)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.2.0:1)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7582)
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: The error message already contains two links where you find the instructions how to initialize the library correctly. Have you read them and performed the described steps?